# Grub 2 not working

Tags: grub2, 14.04, windows-7, bootloader

So here's the thing, I recently installed Ubuntu 14. 
Everything works fine except the boot loader.
I currently have windows 7 installed on another hard drive.
But when I boot the machine I get a black screen with a purple border, and then it boots directly into Ubuntu. I tried re installing grub 2 and loading the boot repair but neither worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can press the *Shift* key after the manufacturer screen and before ubuntu boots... Got to have good timing.
You could also edit your /etc/default/grub and put a # in front of the GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT line. Then run sudo update-grub to complete the change.
  Go to a terminal prompt.

1. `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
2. Make comment out the line that says GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 with a # in front of it.
3. hit control-O (the letter) and enter to save
4. hit control-x  update-to exit
5. `sudo update-grub`   (to make the changes)

You might also be interested in Grub Customizer. It allows you to easily put backgrounds, change default operating system and the timeouts.

Go to a prompt..

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install grub-customizer`

Now you might want to use boot repair..

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trustysudo apt-get install -y boot-repair/saucy/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list"

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
```

Comment: Thanks man, that worked. Although now windows 7 doesn't appear on the grub screen, any ideas why?

Comment: If you go to your bios when booting and change boot orger so the windows drive boots, does it?

Comment: Yeah, windows boots fine if I manually boot the hard drive. Grub doesn't recognize it though.

Answer (score 0):

You can change grub settings with `$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` command. Set
`GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET` variable from true to false then run `$ sudo update-grub` in terminal.

Comment: All that did was add a countdown. Still no options to change operating system.